# post request successful with Postman - unsucessful with fetch-api

Tags: node.js, cookies, postman, fetch-api

I have been bashing my head against the wall for the last 2 days with the following problem.

This is the scenario: When I make a GET request by browsing to a particular website, this website sends a cookie called PHPSESSION="xyz" it then prompts the user to enter a password and subsequently makes a post request to the same URL sending this particular cookie and a hidden form element alongside for verification and upon success sends a pdf.

I can successfully replicate this in Postman.

I make a get request - it sets the cookie - I have password filled into my form-data responds body and manually add the secret string that is added to the form for verification -> send... and I get the pdf - so far so good.

However, I would like to automate this process so that I don't have to painstakingly extract the value of the hidden form by hand but use node.js to make these requests so I wrote the following code:

```
// making the get request to the URL above

    // extract the cookie PHPSESSION value 
    const sessionString =  String(response.headers.get('set-cookie')).substring(10,36)
    
    // parse the body
    const htmlBody = await response.text()
    let doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(htmlBody)
    
    // extract the verification token from the form
    const formToken = await doc.getElementById('verification__token').getAttribute('value')
   


let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('verification[char_1]',0)
    formData.append('verification[char_2]',6)
    formData.append('verification[char_3]',4)
    formData.append('verification[char_4]',5)
    formData.append('verification[char_5]',8)
    formData.append('verification[char_6]',1)
    formData.append('verification[char_7]',7)
    formData.append('verification[char_8]',6)
    formData.append('verification[_token]',formToken) 

    const obj = {
        headers:{
            "Cookie" : `PHPSESSID=${sessionString};`,
            "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            "User-Agent": "PostmanRuntime/7.29.2",
            "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
            "credentials": "include"
        },
        method: "POST",
        body: formData
    }

   const postResponse = await fetch("https://url...",obj)
   
   const r = await postResponse.text()
```

Unfortunately, the post requests fails in node.js - the website is simply redirecting me to back to the form in which I have to type in the password.

I am suspecting it has something to do with the headers / cookie but I simply don't know.
Does anyone spots an obvious mistake?

Thank you

Comment: may be `CORS` issue

Comment: I don't have control over the server. As far as I understand it CORS has something to do with the server?

Answer (score 0):

Solved... after sacrificing the entire weekend to this lovely task.
If anyone comes across a similar problem here is the solution - or at lest what helped me.

https://reqbin.com/curl
https://curlconverter.com

So basically make your request work with curl and then port it.
In my case that looked like this:

```
const x = await fetch('https://yourURL', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Cookie': 'PHPSESSID=lfjdd2uba1bmecr064rt7chvu3; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly;',
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        },
        body: 'verification[_token]=5d5e4d8783daf952d5.UZ661yMyOUtJSQeG1Td7cUtxWqnI2Oaot-xMQevly4o.acH9hXR9SRkwGm30kE9WIggDNpqdl6Ln2rQnOIG9pcEp1tOiYnNLJggZcA&verification[char_1]=0&verification[char_2]=6&verification[char_3]=4&verification[char_4]=5&verification[char_5]=8&verification[char_6]=1&verification[char_7]=7&verification[char_8]=6'
    });
```